# ubuntu 17.10 terminal language broken

Tags: command-line, locale, character-set, korean

```
dup2(soc,0);   // �ٲ� �κ� Ȯ��, ���Ͽ� ����
```

This sentence is one of my code. (comment language is Korean.)

If I view sourcecode in terminal,  this situation happened.

I changed my default language setting to English on purpose because of filename error.

How can I solve this broken character that except change main language?

Comment: What is the encoding of the source code and of your locale? They should both be UTF-8. You can find out by using the `file` command (e.g. `file hello_world.c`) and `locale` command.

Comment: If you view the source code outside of the terminal (like in a text editor or IDE), does the text show correctly?

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))